# Using Entity Framework Model First with Asp.Net Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, entity, membership

I am currently using MVC4 and entity framework model first.
I was wondering how I am supposed to associate the asp.net membership provider tables with entity framework models.

I tried adding membership provider tables into my EF database. But when I make association between UserProfile table from asp.net membership provider and one of my table, another UserProfile table is automatically created and nothing is stored in the original UserProfile table.

Am I supposed to not make any associations between these two and just join table together to get user related information? Is there a work around? Or am I doing it totally wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried adding membership provider tables into my EF database.

You do not need to add/create Membership tables if you use [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). It uses Entity Framework Code First, and it'll create required tables automatically if tables are not found.

**In new Universal Provider, you won't see tables with prefix aspnet_ anymore.**

### Relationship

You can use the UserId of User table as primary key in other tables in which you store user related information.

In the following example, `XXX_Profile` is a custom table. Its primary key is UserId from membership provider's Users table.

[image]