# MobilePin createuserwizard doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I am new to asp.net and I am first time using membership controls in my project.

Here in my project while creating new user I need the Mobile number of the user, How can I enable the MobilePin of CreateUserWizard. Because I saw MobilePin field in `aspnet_membership` table so am thinking we can add the values to mobilePin field from front-end while creating new user.

Can anyone help me?

I did some code but it doesn't work

```
<asp:Label ID="Mobile" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="MobilePIN">Mobile No:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="MobilePIN" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobilePIN" CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Mobile is required." ToolTip="Mobile is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

How do I make mobilepin in `asp.net` membership value insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is nothing to do with ASP.Net Membership.

Rename **TextBox ID** to **MobilePIN** like the following -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MobilePIN" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: i see, how do i make the asp.net mobilepin membership work..?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17623368/296861). Should you have any question regarding ASP.Net Membership, please create a separate question.